# XQuery - Checking if one set contains another set (getting zero results)

Tags: sql, set, xquery, intersection

So I am using this XML database: https://www.dbis.informatik.uni-goettingen.de/Mondial/mondial.xml and this is my problem description:

> "Which countries are members of ALL the organizations whose names
>   start with the word 'International' and are headquartered in Europe?"

Xquery code:

```
let $doc := doc("mondial.xml")/mondial
let $countries := (
  for $c in $doc/country
  let $memShipsSet := $c/tokenize(data(@memberships), '\s')
  let $orgSet := $inter-orgs-eu/data(@id)
  where empty(distinct-values($orgSet[not(.=$memShipsSet)]))
  return <country code="{$c/data(@car_code)}">{$c/data(name)}</country>
)
return $countries
```

(`$inter-orgs-eu` is a sequence/list of all organizations [elements] that have the word 'International' in the name and are headquartered in europe)

The `distinct-values($orgSet[not(.=$memShipsSet)])` function returns the values in `$orgSet` that do not appear in `$memShipsSet` (ref: http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/functx_value-except.html)

However when I run this code it just returns zero results and I can't figure out what I have done wrong. Is it a logic error or something else (I am new to Xquery so it could very well be something obvious that I have missed)?

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:
Full code:

```
let $doc := doc("mondial.xml")/mondial

let $inter-orgs := (
  for $o in $doc/organization
  let $name := xs:string($o/data(name))
  where contains($name,xs:string("International"))
  return $o
)

let $inter-orgs-eu := (
  for $o in $inter-orgs
  let $hq := $o/data(@headq)
  let $city := $doc/country/id($hq)
  let $cCode := $city/data(@country)
  let $country := $doc/country[data(@car_code)=$cCode]
  where $country/encompassed/data(@continent) = 'europe'
  return $o
)

let $countries := (
  for $c in $doc/country
  let $memShipsSet := $c/tokenize(data(@memberships), '\s')
  let $orgSet := $inter-orgs-eu/data(@id)
  where empty(distinct-values($orgSet[not(.=$memShipsSet)]))
  return <country code="{$c/data(@car_code)}">{$c/data(name)}</country>
)
return $countries
```

Comment: The code needed to produce `$inter-orgs-eu` would be helpful. Could you please add it?

Comment: @joewiz I added the full code now in the post edit.

Comment: Thanks! Your code actually works perfectly for me in my XQuery implementation of choice, [eXist-db](https://exist-db.org). "Query returned 244 item(s) in 0.061s." The results appear in the expected form, e.g., `<country code="AL">Albania</country>`. To troubleshoot in your implementation, you might try returning `$inter-orgs` to see if that returns the expected results; if so, then `$inter-orgs-eu`; if so, then pick apart the `$countries` FLWOR expression to confirm each of the clauses (`let`, `where`) are selecting the expected nodes and values. Troubleshooting this way can help.

Comment: @joewiz I have verified every single thing in $countries. Both $memShipsSet and $orgSet contain the correct data. The amount of countries that are returned in your case is wrong because the total amount of countries is 244 (just like you got). You are getting an unfiltered result. If I remove the `where` clause I get the exact same result as you so the problem is somewhere in my `where` condition. I just can't figure out what it is. From my perspective the logic in the condition seems perfectly fine. What am I missing?

Comment: @joewiz I have also verified that the data in $inter-orgs and $inter-orgs-eu is correct. I am using "BaseX" btw if that makes any difference.

Comment: At https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhg I have tried to display a table showing the memberships of all the countries being a member of at least one of the european organizations, it is still a lot of data for a human to read and check but I think there is simply no country that is a member in all organizations like ISO.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Wow... turns out that there really are zero countries that are a member of all the organizations and that there is nothing wrong with my code. Thanks for generating that table man. Really helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there really are 0 countries which are a member of ALL these organizations. So my code was actually working perfectly fine. Thanks to @MartinHonnen for making generating a table of all the countries and the orgs ($inter-orgs-eu) they are a member of over at xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyyiVhg.

There was one small problem in my code though that I have now fixed. $inter-orgs returned all organizations that CONTAINED the word "International" but according to the problem description it should only return organizations that BEGIN WITH the word "International". I fixed it by by using the `starts-with` function in my `where` clause in `$inter-orgs` instead of using the `contains` function. It didn't make a single difference to my end result though (when I return `$countries`).

Final code:

```
let $doc := doc("mondial.xml")/mondial

let $inter-orgs := (
  for $o in $doc/organization
  let $name := xs:string($o/data(name))
  where starts-with($name,xs:string("International"))
  return $o
)

let $inter-orgs-eu := (
  for $o in $inter-orgs
  let $hq := $o/data(@headq)
  let $city := $doc/country/id($hq)
  let $cCode := $city/data(@country)
  let $country := $doc/country[data(@car_code)=$cCode]
  where $country/encompassed/data(@continent) = 'europe'
  return $o
)

let $countries := (
  for $c in $doc/country
  let $memShipsSet := $c/tokenize(data(@memberships), '\s')
  let $orgSet := $inter-orgs-eu/data(@id)
  let $orgsNotInMemSet := distinct-values($orgSet[not(.=$memShipsSet)])
  where empty($orgsNotInMemSet)
  return <country code="{$c/data(@car_code)}">{$c/data(name)}</country>
)

return <root>
 {$countries}
</root>
```

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that the expected result of your "final code" is `<root/>`?

Comment: @joewiz Well since $countries returns 0 results it would only return the root tag. The root element doesn't really need to be there... I just added it just because.